# how to use bitbucket to allow 2 people to work on one project at the same time

Tags: bitbucket

My partner and I are trying to work on the same project in android studio at the same time. We were told that bitbucket was a method by which we could accomplish this task. How? Please make the answer detailed, I am willing to read.

Comment: You should First read about git and specify the question afterwards

Answer (score 0):

All bitbucket is is a place to host your repository privately, it'll be your "remote." What you need to do is learn git, pretty much everything will be the same for github and bitbucket.